# WooCommerce Checkout Error

Tags: plugins, errors

Just started getting this message when trying to "Check Out" in WooCommerce:

{"result":"failure","messages":"

```
\n\t\t\t
Action failed. Please refresh the page and retry.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
Country<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
First Name<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
Last Name<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
Address<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
Town \/ City<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
State<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
Zip<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
Email Address<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
Phone<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
Country<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
First Name<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
Last Name<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
Address<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
Town \/ City<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
State<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
Zip<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
Invalid shipping method.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
Invalid payment method.<\/li>\n\t<\/ul>","refresh":"false"}
```

What the hell is this and how do I make it go away?

Answer (score 1):

Check your WooCommerce System Status to make sure there are no red entries, especially in the Pages section

Test your checkout process with the console active

Check your server error logs for any entries that relate to the pay page

How to use the Google Chrome console : 
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

How to use FireBug for FireFox : 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/

**Andrew, WooNinja**

***I work for WooThemes***

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please note that signatures in posts are discouraged, include any information you want to in your profile. The one nuance is if your answer recommends (or something) the product you are affiliated with, then explicit disclosure is appreciated. Glad to see you involved (we desperately _need_ more people answering [tag:woocommerce] questions)!